# Parse Location into intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, service, location

I have a background service which needs to receive an location. I can see that it is possible to send data to the service through the intent it takes. How to I parse a location object to the intent or is there a better solution?

I want to do something like this:

```
Location location;
intent.putExtra("location", location);
```

I only need to send data to the service at the first startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try type casting:

`Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra((Location) objectName);`

Comment: Sorry I must have described it wrong. I need to insert a Location object in the intent. Like this: intent.putExtra("location", location);

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The Location class implements the Parceable interface and can therefore be put into the intent as an parceableExtra like this:

```
intent.putExtra("location", location);
```

And retreived Again like this:

```
currentLocation = (Location)intent.getParcelableExtra("location");
```